# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. While selecting item from loop for

Tags: python-3.x

I´ve been trying for a while to select an item from a list with the variable of the for loop. But I keep getting this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

The issue dissapears when I change the `i` for a number, but that's not what I want to do. I´ve been looking for similar issues but couldn't manage to get it working. Advise please.

I want this to result as: ['p1', 'q1', 'p2', 'q2', 'p3', 'q3', 'p4', 'q4', 'p5', 'q5']

```
  listcont=[]
  cont=0
  while cont<=5:
    for i in list:
      listcont.append(list[i]+str(cont))
    cont+=1
  return listcont

n=5
list=['q','p']
print(concat(list,n))´´´
```

Comment: don't name your list `list`

Comment: what you want is liscont.append(i + str(cont))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you write `for i in list` you're already iterating over the *elements* of the list, not the indices. So you can use the item directly:

```
listcont.append(i + str(cont))
```

Second, you shouldn't name things `list` since it shadows the built-in of that name and will cause all kinds of trouble.

Third, the `while` loop would be better written as a `for` with a `range`

```
n = 5
my_list = ['q', 'p']
listcont = []
for counter in range(1, n+1):
  for item in my_list:
    listcont.append(item + str(counter))
```

Finally, you can simplify all of this into a list comprehension and make it look neater with an f-string:

```
def make_list(my_list, limit):
    return [f'{item}{counter}' for counter in range(1, limit+1) for item in my_list]

make_list(['p', 'q'], 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use for loop, you must know that if you are using `for i in list` it means that `i` here is the element of the list, and the loop will traverse each element of the list.

While, what you want to do is `for i in range(len(list))`, this will traverse the list with `i` as a number which can gain a value, less than or equal to `len(list) - 1`.

You can learn this very basic thing about for loop [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/for-loop) and hold yourself back from asking such questions.
Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `list` which is a bad idea because `list` is the type of a list in Python. But this isn't the issue. I'm guessing the function you have there, which is missing the declaration, is the function `def concat(list, n)`, and you intended to write `while cont <= n`.

If all this is the case, when you do

```
for i in list:
```

`i` is going to be members of the list, so `'q'`, then `'p'`. In this case `list['p']`  doesn't make any sense.

To get the output you're going for I would do (to be easy to read):

```
def concat(lst, n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        for v in lst:
            result.append('{}{}'.format(v, i+1))
    return result
```

You could do the whole thing in one line with:

```
['{}{}'.format(value, count + 1) for count in range(n) for value in lst]
```